# Got this error in aws -{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"authorization_exception","reason":"User does not have permissions for the requested resource"}

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, serverless, http-status-code-403, opensearch

I am trying to build RAG Pipeline in aws using opensearch Serverless and Bedrock, I have made one collection in opensearch serverless and after I tried to make index in that collection. Index is getting created there and data is also getting stored in that index when i am checking it from sagemaker and Now problem is that when I am trying to open that index from my aws it is showing me authorization error

This is my collection that I made in my opensearch Serverless
[image: This is my collection that I made in my opensearch Serverless]
and here these are my indexes that are getting created inside my collection
[image]

But now the error that i am getting while opening indexes is as below
[image]

Comment: Same problem for me, especially when creating an index +1